# Network related issue while migration from SP2010 to SP2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, migration

While i am migration SP2010 to SP2013 i get an error as
[image: Network related issue]

Kindly please help me to know what is the main cause for this issue . i can also  able to connect my SQL from the server .

Answer (score 0):

Looks like connectivity issue with SQL server.please check following things.

- Check Sql Server Services is running on Sql.
- Also Make Sure sql browser service is running on server.
- Also Check The Firewall, if port 1433/1434 are blocked?
- Try To Test The Sql Connectivity From The Server Using Udl File...You Make That Your Service Account Can Access the content database.
- try to browse the site collection in the browser if you can get the sites.
- Check the uls  logs and get detailed error.
- Also Make Sure No Antivirus Blocking That Connection.
- Check The Service Account Permission On Sql